How is this sentence divided? "まぁまぁと"

A！？ 君…！　死んだとか、法事の場で　忌み言葉を発してはいけません！」


B「こわぁい……助けて…」


C「まぁまぁ君たち」


A「まぁまぁと繰り返しを連想するのも忌み言葉です！」

The dialog is a back and forth between 3 people. They are at a funeral. I used the letters to show who is talking.
I'm stumbled on how to take the last dialog exactly.
The character seems to complain that まぁまぁ is a forbidden word but I can't quite connect it the middle part of the sentence? How is exactly is "と繰り返しを連想する" interact with the first part? I understand it's "Evokes repetition" at least.

The と in "まぁまぁと" is just the plain old quotation particle.
Combining "funeral" with "happening many times" is understandably taboo, so words like まぁまぁ that make people think of repetition ("繰り返しを連想する") are considered unlucky and inappropriate at a funeral. This is what A is conveying.
You can find more information about this type of 忌み言葉, which is apparently called 重ね言葉, on this page.
